# How To Disable Full Site Editing In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a WordPress site built with blocks and full-site editing.  In order to preserve the style of the site, I need to remove the ability for someone in the admin area to utilize the full-site editor (located in "Appearance>>Editor").

[image]

I tried adding `define('DISABLE_FSE', true);` in the wp-config.php file, but that didn't disable the editor.

I'm looking to do this without a plugin as well as being able to maintain the current block-built site; the site should not break when I disable the editing feature.

Answer (score 0):

The capability `edit_theme_options` currently governs FSE.

Remember, multiple users may have that capability and removing the capability will affect all users with that role, so you may need to create a custom role without that capability for the specific user that you don't want to access FSE.